# How to link a sequence to a field with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

In documentation of postgreSQL 9.6, it said to have serial equivalent we have to link the sequence to the field.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/datatype-numeric.html (¤ 8.1.4)

I exactly applied the same code :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_import_trame INCREMENT 1 START 1; 

CREATE TABLE import_trame (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_import_trame'), 
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT pk_import_trame PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_import_trame OWNED BY import_trame.id;
```

But I have an error while executing script with pgAdmin.

Relation "seq_import_trame" already exist".
Code: 42P07
Line 8: ALTER SEQUENCE.....

It's very strange because 42P07 error is duplicate_table.
And if we don't make the link, the sequence is not dropped when we drop the table.

Any idea ?

Comment: So, what happens if you comment out the top line?

Comment: Apparently the sequence already exists, so you can remove the `create sequence` part

Comment: Your code works fine.  You are getting an error on the first line in the script, that is all.  Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4e8752ec6a630bbc037d4b7b8e51ced7.

Comment: It's very strange....in pgAdmin there are 2 mode for execution: 1) execute 2) execute pgscript. With pgscript it's working because probably it commit each command line by line. In normal execution, still an error on ALTER SEQUENCE. I can't remove the first line as u suggest. Sequence doesnt exist before, and its necessary to create it with particular name (too bad my client require this convention name).

Comment: The sequence already exists, use `CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem on DB Fiddle:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_import_trame INCREMENT 1 START 1; 

CREATE TABLE import_trame (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_import_trame'), 
    CONSTRAINT pk_import_trame PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_import_trame OWNED BY import_trame.id;
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4YK2Qc4yLbKoF5xfcXvHvS/0)

Check again your script.

Comment: Seems a pgAdmin problem. On SQL execution it returns an error on ALTER SEQUENCE line. With pgScript execution it's OK. Strange.

Comment: Not Really, but I will solve the topic cause it’s not a PostgreSQL pb...it’s pgAdmin :(